# wso2Api Manager Call Rest Backend with Soap Request and Response

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Our  Requirement  is  that  I  had  Backend  Api Service  (Rest  Services)  which  have  Http  Method  Post,  and  Request  as  JSON  which  will  call  wso2APi  Manager  as  Reqest  and  Response  as  SOAP

### what  i  had  tested  was

For  Creating  API  i  had  used  ,Already  wsdl  of  our  Dummy  Services,also  Sequence and  Out  Sequence.

But  when  i  am  calling  Rest  Back-end  Services  ,it  is  not  Response  Any  OutPut  to  me

Please  guide  me  how  i  will  meet  this  Scinario

Answer (score 0):

Can you directly call the backend service? If so , then you can compare the request going from AM t0 Backend verser the direct backend call (headers, body etc.)  and check what is missing. to check the AM-Backend request you can enable wirelogs. see http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html